# How can I access Python instance variable of type set in the right way

Tags: python, class, variables, instance

Can anyone tell why, why the length of my instance variable( with type set) do not work the way as I though.

When I called `a.addToSet("xx")`, I thought the value of `len(b.aSet)` and `len(ExampleClass.aSet)` should return zero, so as `a.aInt` be 100 and rest be 0, while the console print the 1 for all the three instance.

Many thanks

==========================

Let's say, we have a class called ExampleClass with two variable: aSet and aInt.

```
class ExampleClass():
    aSet = set()
    aInt = 0
    def addToSet(self,aValue):
        self.aSet.add(aValue)

a=ExampleClass()
b=ExampleClass()
a.addToSet("xx")
a.aInt=100

print len(a.aSet)
print len(b.aSet)
print len(ExampleClass.aSet)
print a.aInt
print b.aInt
print ExampleClass.aInt
```

## OUTPUT

1

1

1

100

0

0

Comment: Briefly: you created a class variable, not instance variables.

Comment: And see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959097/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-variables-in-python) as well.

Comment: Sorry for duplicate, I have one more question, does python distinguish the simple date type and complex type?  cause as the result showed, the aInt works just like the instance variable.

Comment: What do you mean by simple and complex?

Comment: just like primitive data types (int, float, etc), and non primitive data types(String, user defined Class) in Java. Which act difference way ( when pass into the method as parameter.

Comment: [Everything is an object in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294953/how-does-everything-is-an-object-even-work). Just watch out for which ones are mutable or immutable, what's considered truthy and falsey, and so on. Python is [pass-by-reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

Comment: Thank you very much